# spring boot + load secret manager secrets from different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, aws-secrets-manager

I'm developing a new Spring Boot application that will interact with an AWS-Postgres database. The serverless DB is hosted in a different AWS account and its secrets are stored in Secretmanager.

How can I effectively fetch the DB credentials from a cross-account secret manager?

In a POC, I did this by constructing a secret manager client using `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentials` like this

```
AWSSecretsManager awsSecretsManager = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider). // AssumeRole ( cross account session token)
                .withRegion("us-west-2")
                .build();
```

I executed the following steps to solve the use-case but I don't think it is a clean solution.

1. Fetched credentials
2. Populate env variables using the above db credentials
3. Let spring-boot/jpa to setup db connection

I think it could be solved using the `spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` but didn't find any example/reference on how to configure it so that it can fetch credentials from SecretManager that is in a different AWS account.

How might the above work, or any better solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it can be further simplified on code side.

Let's say accountA has secrets and accountB is your app account. Current implementation does the following:

- A client is created inside the accountB using accountA credentials (AssumeRole is followed and is a best practice)
- Secrets are fetched and then used.

What could be done:

- Use resource based policy in accountA that let's the IAM User and/or IAM Role in accountB have access to the secrets placed in accountA.
- Update the KMS key policy in accountA for the key that is used to encrypt/decrypt secrets. Let the same IAM User and/or Role have access to that KMS key. So that they can use it.
- Update the IAM Policy for the IAM User and/or Role in accountB, explicitly allowing it to use the secrets and KMS keys of accountA.

Now, you are able to access the secrets using the same IAM User/Role that is used for the app and theoretically `spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` should fetch the secrets from accountA as well (I have not tested it for myself).

The least benefit you will get is not creating assumedRole client for different account. [More details on AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-access-secrets-across-aws-accounts-by-attaching-resource-based-policies/)

Comment: Thanks @amsh. Will try this for sure.

Comment: Yes, it works. Unfortunately, I can't use resource-based access due to some security recommendations. In this process, I found the following AWS lib which helps to rotate secrets. https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-jdbc